# animated plot axis label werid moving

Tags: pgfplots, animate, performance

When I use the [`animate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=en) package the axis labels start to dance and bounce as the scale moves, how do I stop this from happening? Also:

- How do I make the animation smoother? Increasing the framerate only makes it faster.
- How do I improve the compilation performance? I read somewhere that the samples have huge impact, but using `600` already makes the plot look weird. (It's currently taking **3~4 mins**!)
- I also wish to have infinite domain, but gives me error of `dimension too large`

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,autopause,poster=2,buttonbg=1]{15}
\multiframe{60}{rY=0.5+0.5, rX=100+200}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
 %   axis equal image=true,
      width=10cm,
      height=10cm,
      scale only axis,
      minor tick num=3,
      xmin=0.05,
      xmax=\rX,%10000,
      ymin=0.05,
      ymax=\rY,
      ylabel = Yada y,
      xlabel = Yada x
    ]
      \addplot[red,thick,smooth,samples=600,domain=0:5000] {0.8*x^0.15};
      \addplot[blue,thick,domain=0:5000]  {2.5 + 0.00032*x^1}; %domain=0:5000
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a general rule, if you increase both the number of frames and the frame rate by the same factor, your animation will become smoother without speeding up. I'll have a closer look at this code and report back if I have any more suggestions or a solution.

Comment: That worked fine Ulysses, except that now the file takes 5 mins to compile and becomes a 4 MB pdf, lol. But it's really smooth with 100 frames.

Comment: Good to know it helped. Not sure what to suggest about the compile times and file size though. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All frames need to share the same bounding box.

With `animate`, all frames starting from the second one are sequeezed/stretched to fit into the first frame's bounding box which is used to scale the animation widget.

To ensure that all frames have the same size, put some thing like

```
   \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (12,12);
```

at the start of the `tikzpicture`  environment. You may want to play with the `rectangle` corner coordinates to reduce the white margin around the plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,autopause,poster=2,buttonbg=1]{15}
\multiframe{60}{rY=0.5+0.5, rX=100+200}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (12,12);
    \begin{axis}[
 %   axis equal image=true,
      width=10cm,
      height=10cm,
      scale only axis,
      minor tick num=3,
      xmin=0.05,
      xmax=\rX,%10000,
      ymin=0.05,
      ymax=\rY,
      ylabel = Yada y,
      xlabel = Yada x
    ]
      \addplot[red,thick,smooth,samples=600,domain=0:5000] {0.8*x^0.15};
      \addplot[blue,thick,domain=0:5000]  {2.5 + 0.00032*x^1}; %domain=0:5000
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

As for compilation performance, there is not very much to be done except externalizing the TikZ graphics. The plots are given as analytical expressions which are computed by the PGF math engine (implemented in TeX).

Comment: Thanks AlexG, could you explain a little about this procedure of externalizing the TikZ graph, what exactly do you mean ? Like having each frame as a individual pdf then loading then again?

Comment: @G.Bay Exactly. This is a tikz/pgfplots feature for reducing compilation time. It is explained in the manuals. You could also search this site (TeX.SX) for  "`[pgfplots] [externalize]`".